# Working of Whatsapp adding contacts

Tags: android, ios, iphone

How can I tell if people in my phone contact list are other users of my app? I saw this feature in WhatsApp.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182897/get-all-my-app-users-from-contacts

Comment: you asked the same question already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182897/get-all-my-app-users-from-contacts

Comment: I did not get any solution for that. I think I should Delete the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload all user contacts to the app server. You need the permission from the user first, then upload the contacts, and compare the uploaded list with the contact detail of users already on the server.

Comment: Thanks Nitin I know this kind of flow. The thing where I got stuck is that while registering phone number, user will enter in standard format that I will provide a textBox (For Example countryCode - (91) and then 10 digit number) but actually the contacts saved within for different phones will have different format i.e some may have leading + or 0 or -(seperators) etc. So should I parse the contact listing of each user first and then save up on my server? Is that correct ? Or is their any easier solution?

Comment: I think you need to format the contact details to a standard format in the server. Since you creating the app for many platforms it will be easy. I am not familiar with that actually.